# How to pick filename by string pattern?

Tags: ruby, regex

For instance, I have files with following names:

```
435_red.rb
32_red_blue.rb
9921_blue.rb
```

In the first case, I need to get **9921_blue.rb** file by the pattern **blue**.

In the second case, I have to fetch **435_red.rb** file by the pattern **red**.

In the third case, I need to have **32_red_blue.rb** file by the pattern **red_blue**.

How can I achieve this?

I try using something like this

```
pattern = "blue"

result = Dir.glob(File.join(directory, '**.*')).select do |f|
           f.match(pattern)
         end
```

But result will return two values:

```
["32_red_blue.rb", "9921_blue.rb",]
```

rather than just **"9921_blue.rb"**

Comment: This [`/(_[^.]+)/`](https://regex101.com/r/sO8wN8/2)?

Comment: Can you clarify that the search pattern must immediately follow the numbers and `_`, and be followed by `.rb` rather than additional word characters?

Comment: guessing by your examples, dont you want to match more specifically for `"red.rb", "blue.rb" and "red_blue.rb"` ?

Comment: @shivam Yes, I want to match them by the given string. If I pass "red" that doesn't mean I want to fetch also "red_blue", I want only "red" file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
def get_files_by_pattern(dir, pattern)
  Dir.glob(File.join(dir, '/*.rb')).select do |f|
    f.split("/")[-1][/^\d*\_#{pattern}\.rb$/]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to use the right pattern, using a regular expression (regexp). Perhaps:

```
pattern = /\A\d+_blue\.rb\Z/
```

regexp's are powerful tools for pattern matching strings. Some resources:

- http://regexone.com/
- http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/
- http://rubular.com/